# Is there a good Rhino Javascript compiler available as Maven plug-in?

Tags: maven-2, rhino

Commons JCI project doesn't seem to be maintained since a long time. Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven does allow you to use Ant tasks using the [AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).  So you could use the [Mozilla compiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_JavaScript_Compiler) through an Ant task, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231550/has-anyone-used-or-written-an-ant-task-to-compile-rhino-javascript-to-java-byte).  Not pretty, but I bet it will work.