# Javascript to Java using Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

How can I get the .class of a javascript file? Rhino claims we can compile a javascript file and get the .class file of it. I have gone through their documentation but didn’t found such. Instead I have found that they use java objects from javascript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843996/how-to-compile-rhino-javascript-files-to-class-bytecode-for-java-at-runtime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231550/has-anyone-used-or-written-an-ant-task-to-compile-rhino-javascript-to-java-byt/

Comment: @Harshana - you have to be aware that in rare cases you may enounter an issue with compiling javascripts to `.class`  due to [the bytecode size limit](http://coachwei.sys-con.com/node/676073/) imposed by the JVM, thouht I think it will be rare, more likely if you compile very large code like [coffeescript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/extras/coffee-script.js)

Answer (score 2):

There you go: [Rhino Project - JavaScript Compiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/JavaScript_Compiler)